# Convert image to code (TikZ? PSTricks?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, pstricks, plot

I have a ... pdf file, which contains figures of plots such as the following:

[image]

[image]

Now the second plot isn't too hard to draw on TikZ (I assume... I hope? I don't have any experience apart from drawing circuits!), but it's figures like the first picture that I'm more worried about. I want to re-draw them in code (like in TikZ or any package really) so that they appear in higher quality than if I were to just take a screenshot and post that in my LaTeX doc.

Are there any tools that can automatically convert images like these into code? It doesn't have to be perfect, I can tweak it as necessary, I would just like at least the basic code done so that I don't have to start new with every single one. Even examples found online don't really match up to something like the first picture, and I'd rather not go through mountains of examples/pdfs/how-tos to draw something relatively simple. So how can I tackle something like the first drawing in code easily, i.e. convert it to compilable code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know any program which can convert from pdf to tikz, pstricks, ... but both figures can be easily drawn with any of these tools if you know their mathematical expression and experimental values.

Comment: If you accept a brute force solutions, you can try drawing by hand (tikz, pstricks, ...) over your pdf figures as background and one finished forget the background figure. This answer can be helpful in this case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/1952

Comment: you can use http://vectormagic.com/home  to convert bitmap image to svg

Comment: In this particular case, I note that the caption does give a reference for the data!  If you have institutional library access you can get it here: http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.88.559

Comment: Google returned these: http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/  and http://getdata-graph-digitizer.com/ . Data files can be loaded using `pgfplots`, for example.

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend a combination of tools:

1. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)
2. [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz/)

Once you install Inkscape, you can put svg2tikz in your `./config/inkscape/extensions` directory and restart the program to get this functionality.  Now, you just need to convert the bitmap to a vector.  Inkscape has this functionality built-in (version 0.48).

Step-by-step instructions:

1. Import bitmap `File->Import`
2. Select bitmap and choose `Path->Trace Bitmap`
3. Adjust the options to your liking, depending on the image my options were

   - single scan, brightness cutoff of 0.8
   - suppress speckles at 6px
   - Smooth corners at 1.00
   - Optimize paths at 5.00
4. Select the newly-created path.  You may wish to choose `Path->Simplify` at this point but I find Inkscape's simplify algorithm to be overly aggressive.
5. You may also want to separate the path into regions by using `Path->Break Apart`.  This will cause some consternation where you have white-on-black as in '0' or 'B'.  You should choose the sub-paths you actually want and re-combine them using `Path->Exclusion`.
6. Touch up the image.  I'd recommend replacing the letters/numbers with actual text as well as possibly replacing the axes with single, stroked lines.  This will greatly reduce the overall size of your tikz path.
7. Export the graphic using `Extensions->Export->Export to TiKZ path`  The results are below.

I made a couple modifications to fit the 40,000 character limit of SE.  I replaced the text before exporting and then added the axis labels by hand.  I've only posted the code for the first but put both image outputs below.  The procedure is the same.  I also truncated the decimal output of the export to 2 digits (instead of the 4) using grep.

[image: First Plot]
[image: Second Plot]

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=black] (232.51,182.05) .. controls (232.30,182.11) and
  (232.06,183.60) .. (231.95,186.49) .. controls (231.51,198.05) and
  (231.46,200.52) .. (231.65,200.89) .. controls (231.87,201.33) and
  (231.69,215.09) .. (231.26,230.25) .. controls (231.19,232.65) and
  (231.12,235.49) .. (231.09,236.55) .. controls (231.07,237.61) and
  (230.99,238.98) .. (230.91,239.59) .. controls (230.69,241.43) and
  (230.58,251.83) .. (230.79,252.21) .. controls (230.90,252.41) and
  (230.90,253.38) .. (230.81,254.55) .. controls (230.71,255.65) and
  (230.70,256.73) .. (230.78,256.96) .. controls (230.86,257.18) and
  (230.83,257.64) .. (230.72,257.97) .. controls (230.52,258.54) and
  (230.29,268.70) .. (230.08,285.80) .. controls (230.03,289.37) and
  (229.94,294.78) .. (229.88,297.82) .. controls (229.81,301.03) and
  (229.85,303.56) .. (229.96,303.85) .. controls (230.18,304.43) and
  (230.19,305.41) .. (230.09,310.53) .. controls (229.99,315.08) and
  (229.91,314.90) .. (232.14,314.92) .. controls (233.01,314.93) and
  (240.76,315.02) .. (249.36,315.12) .. controls (257.95,315.23) and
  (265.13,315.24) .. (265.30,315.15) .. controls (265.89,314.83) and
  (276.85,314.87) .. (295.36,315.24) .. controls (304.98,315.44) and
  (316.76,315.40) .. (317.35,315.17) .. controls (317.75,315.01) and
  (318.37,315.01) .. (319.54,315.17) .. controls (320.43,315.29) and
  (321.55,315.35) .. (322.02,315.30) .. controls (322.49,315.25) and
  (324.84,315.29) .. (327.24,315.38) .. controls (337.41,315.77) and
  (367.58,316.06) .. (368.62,315.78) .. controls (368.93,315.70) and
  (371.46,315.70) .. (374.26,315.78) .. controls (382.09,316.02) and
  (391.74,316.19) .. (405.73,316.35) .. controls (412.77,316.44) and
  (418.71,316.45) .. (418.94,316.39) .. controls (419.16,316.33) and
  (422.54,316.27) .. (426.45,316.27) .. controls (433.48,316.25) and
  (434.07,316.21) .. (434.07,315.65) .. controls (434.07,314.92) and
  (424.25,314.56) .. (421.25,315.18) .. controls (420.35,315.36) and
  (419.95,315.37) .. (419.56,315.19) -- (419.04,314.95) --
  (419.04,311.68) .. controls (419.04,308.49) and (418.56,306.69) ..
  (418.51,309.68) .. controls (418.40,315.63) and (418.89,315.06) ..
  (414.12,314.98) .. controls (411.97,314.94) and (409.47,314.94) ..
  (408.58,314.96) .. controls (407.68,314.99) and (406.40,315.00) ..
  (405.73,314.99) .. controls (398.61,314.88) and (388.32,314.74) ..
  (381.32,314.64) .. controls (370.87,314.50) and (372.12,315.00) ..
  (372.12,310.97) .. controls (372.12,308.76) and (372.05,307.61) ..
  (371.90,307.51) .. controls (371.47,307.25) and (371.36,307.89) ..
  (371.34,310.78) .. controls (371.31,314.24) and (371.32,314.19) ..
  (370.19,314.63) .. controls (369.17,315.02) and (346.87,314.92) ..
  (343.18,314.51) .. controls (341.27,314.30) and (332.88,314.07) ..
  (328.38,314.10) .. controls (325.00,314.13) and (325.21,314.37) ..
  (325.21,310.55) .. controls (325.21,308.04) and (325.16,307.42) ..
  (324.94,307.42) .. controls (324.55,307.42) and (324.41,308.51) ..
  (324.40,311.42) -- (324.39,313.88) -- (322.92,314.00) .. controls
  (322.11,314.07) and (320.76,314.20) .. (319.93,314.30) .. controls
  (319.05,314.40) and (317.54,314.40) .. (316.37,314.30) .. controls
  (315.26,314.20) and (306.27,314.06) .. (296.41,313.97) .. controls
  (279.41,313.83) and (278.45,313.80) .. (278.20,313.45) .. controls
  (278.00,313.19) and (277.93,312.28) .. (277.94,310.18) .. controls
  (277.95,307.42) and (277.85,306.69) .. (277.51,306.90) .. controls
  (277.42,306.96) and (277.34,308.35) .. (277.32,310.00) .. controls
  (277.30,311.65) and (277.23,313.15) .. (277.17,313.35) .. controls
  (277.07,313.66) and (276.54,313.71) .. (272.14,313.82) .. controls
  (262.94,314.05) and (247.71,313.93) .. (235.55,313.52) --
  (232.30,313.42) -- (232.05,312.89) .. controls (231.85,312.46) and
  (231.86,312.03) .. (232.10,310.65) .. controls (232.26,309.72) and
  (232.43,308.22) .. (232.48,307.32) .. controls (232.58,305.32) and
  (232.90,303.32) .. (233.28,302.25) .. controls (233.43,301.80) and
  (233.67,300.79) .. (233.82,300.01) .. controls (233.96,299.23) and
  (234.15,298.50) .. (234.23,298.39) .. controls (234.31,298.28) and
  (234.43,297.82) .. (234.49,297.37) .. controls (234.55,296.92) and
  (234.79,295.83) .. (235.04,294.93) .. controls (235.28,294.04) and
  (235.56,292.76) .. (235.66,292.09) .. controls (235.77,291.42) and
  (236.12,289.96) .. (236.44,288.84) .. controls (236.76,287.72) and
  (237.09,286.49) .. (237.17,286.11) .. controls (237.46,284.77) and
  (238.11,284.28) .. (238.69,284.98) .. controls (239.25,285.66) and
  (239.52,285.30) .. (239.03,284.53) .. controls (238.14,283.10) and
  (238.15,282.98) .. (239.41,281.70) .. controls (240.59,280.50) and
  (240.84,279.46) .. (240.25,278.16) .. controls (240.13,277.90) and
  (240.25,277.81) .. (240.84,277.71) .. controls (242.04,277.52) and
  (242.14,277.32) .. (242.14,275.39) .. controls (242.14,273.98) and
  (242.23,273.53) .. (242.58,272.96) .. controls (242.95,272.36) and
  (243.00,272.05) .. (242.91,270.70) .. controls (242.82,269.35) and
  (242.88,269.01) .. (243.29,268.14) .. controls (243.56,267.59) and
  (243.77,267.01) .. (243.77,266.85) .. controls (243.77,266.34) and
  (244.85,263.47) .. (245.23,262.97) .. controls (245.43,262.71) and
  (245.60,262.38) .. (245.60,262.24) .. controls (245.60,261.54) and
  (246.20,261.48) .. (246.80,262.12) .. controls (248.00,263.41) and
  (248.45,262.76) .. (247.32,261.35) .. controls (246.30,260.06) and
  (246.48,259.07) .. (247.93,257.96) .. controls (248.32,257.66) and
  (248.64,257.25) .. (248.64,257.06) .. controls (248.64,256.54) and
  (249.14,256.21) .. (249.70,256.35) .. controls (251.38,256.77) and
  (253.18,253.92) .. (252.10,252.54) .. controls (251.33,251.57) and
  (252.61,248.90) .. (254.40,247.73) .. controls (254.84,247.44) and
  (255.20,247.02) .. (255.26,246.71) .. controls (255.70,244.56) and
  (255.97,244.45) .. (257.39,245.78) .. controls (257.95,246.30) and
  (258.49,246.67) .. (258.60,246.60) .. controls (258.85,246.45) and
  (258.59,245.93) .. (258.02,245.42) .. controls (256.58,244.11) and
  (257.57,241.92) .. (259.71,241.67) .. controls (260.77,241.56) and
  (260.80,241.53) .. (261.00,240.36) .. controls (261.13,239.62) and
  (261.24,239.46) .. (261.79,239.28) .. controls (263.39,238.76) and
  (263.72,238.29) .. (263.65,236.63) -- (263.57,235.13) --
  (264.69,234.10) .. controls (265.66,233.21) and (265.89,233.09) ..
  (266.51,233.16) .. controls (267.12,233.23) and (267.37,233.10) ..
  (268.22,232.35) .. controls (269.44,231.26) and (269.87,231.25) ..
  (270.88,232.28) .. controls (272.28,233.71) and (272.72,233.24) ..
  (271.39,231.73) .. controls (270.38,230.58) and (270.38,230.33) ..
  (271.39,229.34) .. controls (271.93,228.81) and (272.20,228.37) ..
  (272.20,228.01) .. controls (272.20,227.61) and (272.49,227.22) ..
  (273.37,226.47) .. controls (275.32,224.81) and (275.21,224.87) ..
  (275.63,225.25) .. controls (276.11,225.69) and (276.09,225.69) ..
  (277.08,224.87) .. controls (278.17,223.95) and (280.12,224.56) ..
  (280.12,225.81) .. controls (280.12,225.91) and (280.26,225.99) ..
  (280.43,225.99) .. controls (280.88,225.99) and (280.80,225.65) ..
  (280.12,224.67) .. controls (279.22,223.36) and (279.27,223.18) ..
  (280.38,223.64) .. controls (281.97,224.31) and (283.54,222.70) ..
  (283.30,220.65) .. controls (283.15,219.39) and (284.87,218.12) ..
  (285.27,219.18) .. controls (285.47,219.70) and (285.96,219.53) ..
  (286.94,218.58) .. controls (288.01,217.54) and (288.29,217.57) ..
  (289.33,218.81) .. controls (290.48,220.18) and (290.89,219.50) ..
  (289.77,218.09) .. controls (288.80,216.87) and (288.85,216.60) ..
  (290.23,215.68) .. controls (291.51,214.83) and (294.39,213.33) ..
  (295.17,213.10) .. controls (295.60,212.98) and (298.19,211.84) ..
  (300.53,210.74) .. controls (301.35,210.36) and (303.57,209.69) ..
  (304.90,209.43) .. controls (305.29,209.36) and (305.80,209.17) ..
  (306.03,209.03) .. controls (306.26,208.88) and (306.94,208.63) ..
  (307.55,208.46) .. controls (308.16,208.29) and (308.86,208.09) ..
  (309.10,208.01) .. controls (309.46,207.90) and (309.63,208.02) ..
  (310.06,208.70) .. controls (311.15,210.43) and (313.49,209.97) ..
  (314.04,207.93) .. controls (314.27,207.06) and (314.71,206.69) ..
  (315.54,206.69) .. controls (315.82,206.69) and (316.36,206.43) ..
  (316.72,206.11) .. controls (317.09,205.79) and (317.71,205.48) ..
  (318.10,205.42) .. controls (319.66,205.19) and (323.64,204.35) ..
  (326.53,203.64) .. controls (328.78,203.08) and (329.70,202.94) ..
  (330.07,203.08) .. controls (330.46,203.22) and (330.89,203.10) ..
  (332.25,202.44) .. controls (333.17,201.99) and (334.18,201.62) ..
  (334.48,201.62) .. controls (334.78,201.62) and (335.63,201.51) ..
  (336.36,201.39) -- (337.69,201.15) -- (338.10,201.73) .. controls
  (339.62,203.85) and (340.95,203.87) .. (342.17,201.79) .. controls
  (342.93,200.49) and (343.44,200.30) .. (346.57,200.09) .. controls
  (347.72,200.02) and (349.30,199.82) .. (350.09,199.67) .. controls
  (352.41,199.20) and (353.37,199.28) .. (354.18,199.99) .. controls
  (355.18,200.87) and (355.84,200.79) .. (357.22,199.59) .. controls
  (357.76,199.12) and (358.10,199.02) .. (359.66,198.89) .. controls
  (364.49,198.50) and (366.67,198.38) .. (368.85,198.37) .. controls
  (370.15,198.36) and (372.39,198.25) .. (373.85,198.13) .. controls
  (378.10,197.78) and (379.63,197.71) .. (385.42,197.63) .. controls
  (388.44,197.59) and (391.64,197.47) .. (392.53,197.36) .. controls
  (396.04,196.93) and (397.84,196.81) .. (398.42,196.98) .. controls
  (398.75,197.07) and (399.32,197.15) .. (399.67,197.15) .. controls
  (400.14,197.15) and (400.47,197.33) .. (400.91,197.84) .. controls
  (402.22,199.32) and (403.18,199.29) .. (404.65,197.71) --
  (405.60,196.69) -- (411.96,196.87) .. controls (418.84,197.06) and
  (422.74,197.03) .. (423.90,196.77) .. controls (424.30,196.68) and
  (425.40,196.67) .. (426.35,196.75) .. controls (428.57,196.93) and
  (429.77,196.23) .. (428.72,195.36) .. controls (428.38,195.07) and
  (414.15,194.74) .. (409.18,194.91) .. controls (405.89,195.02) and
  (404.87,194.94) .. (404.16,194.51) .. controls (403.30,193.98) and
  (402.37,193.99) .. (401.67,194.55) .. controls (401.16,194.95) and
  (400.84,195.00) .. (398.17,195.05) .. controls (396.22,195.08) and
  (394.91,195.20) .. (394.29,195.41) .. controls (393.52,195.66) and
  (391.66,195.73) .. (384.20,195.80) .. controls (379.18,195.85) and
  (374.43,195.99) .. (373.64,196.11) .. controls (372.86,196.23) and
  (370.30,196.37) .. (367.96,196.43) .. controls (365.61,196.49) and
  (362.99,196.65) .. (362.12,196.78) .. controls (360.41,197.04) and
  (357.96,196.83) .. (356.75,196.32) .. controls (355.89,195.96) and
  (355.73,196.17) .. (356.36,196.80) .. controls (357.47,197.91) and
  (357.09,199.41) .. (355.68,199.55) .. controls (354.58,199.66) and
  (354.18,199.12) .. (354.34,197.71) .. controls (354.46,196.71) and
  (354.43,196.56) .. (354.16,196.67) .. controls (353.99,196.73) and
  (353.84,196.87) .. (353.84,196.98) .. controls (353.84,197.50) and
  (352.24,197.81) .. (348.94,197.92) -- (345.57,198.02) --
  (345.20,197.43) .. controls (343.76,195.12) and (342.07,195.09) ..
  (340.98,197.36) .. controls (340.38,198.61) and (339.56,199.10) ..
  (337.76,199.27) .. controls (336.94,199.35) and (336.15,199.52) ..
  (336.00,199.65) .. controls (335.24,200.28) and (333.48,200.18) ..
  (332.40,199.45) .. controls (331.50,198.84) and (331.25,198.76) ..
  (330.60,198.89) .. controls (329.80,199.04) and (329.72,199.10) ..
  (329.02,200.17) .. controls (328.24,201.36) and (327.69,201.63) ..
  (325.40,201.92) .. controls (324.23,202.07) and (322.82,202.33) ..
  (322.26,202.50) .. controls (321.70,202.67) and (320.41,202.91) ..
  (319.38,203.05) -- (317.51,203.30) -- (316.79,202.66) .. controls
  (315.58,201.61) and (313.50,202.13) .. (313.14,203.59) .. controls
  (312.94,204.37) and (312.49,204.82) .. (311.73,204.98) .. controls
  (311.38,205.06) and (310.57,205.38) .. (309.93,205.70) .. controls
  (309.29,206.02) and (308.52,206.29) .. (308.20,206.29) .. controls
  (307.89,206.30) and (307.09,206.53) .. (306.42,206.81) .. controls
  (305.75,207.09) and (304.53,207.49) .. (303.71,207.71) .. controls
  (302.88,207.93) and (301.64,208.38) .. (300.96,208.71) .. controls
  (298.94,209.69) and (298.22,209.73) .. (297.30,208.86) .. controls
  (295.71,207.36) and (293.53,208.56) .. (293.53,210.94) .. controls
  (293.53,211.59) and (293.09,212.00) .. (292.10,212.28) .. controls
  (291.82,212.36) and (291.37,212.63) .. (291.09,212.89) .. controls
  (289.67,214.18) and (287.65,214.78) .. (286.57,214.23) .. controls
  (285.68,213.78) and (285.49,213.93) .. (285.91,214.74) .. controls
  (286.73,216.32) and (282.35,218.58) .. (280.85,217.35) .. controls
  (279.07,215.90) and (277.44,216.89) .. (277.36,219.49) .. controls
  (277.33,220.48) and (277.26,220.79) .. (277.05,220.73) .. controls
  (275.98,220.42) and (275.79,220.44) .. (275.95,220.83) .. controls
  (276.35,221.79) and (276.30,221.88) .. (275.15,222.77) .. controls
  (274.51,223.25) and (273.70,223.83) .. (273.34,224.06) .. controls
  (272.98,224.28) and (272.09,225.00) .. (271.38,225.66) .. controls
  (269.76,227.13) and (269.39,227.28) .. (268.44,226.89) .. controls
  (267.27,226.40) and (265.57,227.07) .. (265.21,228.16) .. controls
  (265.14,228.36) and (264.73,228.79) .. (264.30,229.11) --
  (263.51,229.69) -- (263.44,231.38) .. controls (263.35,233.66) and
  (262.96,234.21) .. (261.09,234.71) .. controls (260.44,234.88) and
  (260.11,235.13) .. (259.67,235.79) .. controls (259.13,236.59) and
  (259.02,236.65) .. (258.05,236.71) .. controls (256.69,236.79) and
  (256.59,236.95) .. (256.44,239.21) .. controls (256.25,241.99) and
  (255.82,242.42) .. (254.33,241.32) .. controls (253.20,240.49) and
  (251.60,240.92) .. (250.93,242.24) .. controls (250.47,243.15) and
  (250.59,247.26) .. (251.08,247.56) .. controls (251.76,247.99) and
  (251.10,249.45) .. (249.20,251.71) .. controls (248.78,252.21) and
  (248.44,252.71) .. (248.44,252.82) .. controls (248.44,252.93) and
  (247.93,254.09) .. (247.30,255.40) .. controls (245.49,259.15) and
  (245.13,259.49) .. (244.35,258.18) .. controls (243.91,257.43) and
  (243.43,257.26) .. (243.24,257.78) .. controls (243.17,257.96) and
  (243.41,258.41) .. (243.85,258.89) .. controls (244.80,259.94) and
  (244.77,260.24) .. (243.67,261.32) .. controls (242.83,262.14) and
  (242.75,262.31) .. (242.74,263.25) .. controls (242.73,263.81) and
  (242.64,264.77) .. (242.53,265.39) .. controls (242.42,266.00) and
  (242.28,266.81) .. (242.21,267.17) .. controls (242.09,267.89) and
  (240.98,268.84) .. (240.27,268.84) .. controls (239.64,268.84) and
  (238.96,269.71) .. (238.81,270.71) .. controls (238.64,271.88) and
  (238.69,271.87) .. (235.14,271.86) .. controls (231.11,271.85) and
  (231.21,272.33) .. (231.91,256.98) .. controls (232.01,254.90) and
  (231.97,253.96) .. (231.77,253.36) .. controls (231.55,252.69) and
  (231.56,251.09) .. (231.79,244.09) .. controls (231.94,239.44) and
  (232.08,234.92) .. (232.10,234.05) .. controls (232.16,231.89) and
  (232.65,231.66) .. (237.17,231.68) .. controls (238.84,231.69) and
  (239.42,231.43) .. (238.81,230.96) .. controls (238.33,230.60) and
  (237.81,230.57) .. (237.23,230.89) .. controls (236.49,231.28) and
  (234.03,231.26) .. (233.07,230.85) -- (232.22,230.49) --
  (232.31,227.27) .. controls (232.35,225.51) and (232.44,222.21) ..
  (232.50,219.94) .. controls (232.90,205.61) and (232.91,205.06) ..
  (232.76,200.70) .. controls (232.62,196.52) and (232.87,191.43) ..
  (233.23,190.99) .. controls (233.56,190.58) and (233.56,190.53) ..
  (233.25,190.17) .. controls (232.96,189.85) and (232.90,189.27) ..
  (232.90,186.21) .. controls (232.90,183.36) and (232.72,181.99) ..
  (232.51,182.05) -- cycle(237.74,190.27) .. controls
  (235.42,190.26) and (234.44,190.40) .. (234.86,190.67) .. controls
  (235.28,190.94) and (239.56,190.80) .. (239.66,190.52) .. controls
  (239.71,190.35) and (239.15,190.28) .. (237.74,190.27) --
  cycle(402.66,194.93) .. controls (403.87,194.86) and
  (404.81,196.27) .. (403.96,197.41) .. controls (403.58,197.92) and
  (402.57,198.04) .. (402.03,197.66) .. controls (401.40,197.21) and
  (401.36,195.45) .. (401.96,195.12) .. controls (402.20,195.00) and
  (402.43,194.94) .. (402.66,194.93) -- cycle(340.42,199.38) ..
  controls (341.53,199.38) and (342.10,201.18) .. (341.25,202.02) ..
  controls (340.37,202.91) and (338.82,202.32) .. (338.82,201.09) ..
  controls (338.82,200.51) and (339.88,199.38) .. (340.42,199.38) --
  cycle(315.20,202.71) .. controls (315.24,202.72) and
  (315.28,202.73) .. (315.32,202.74) .. controls (316.50,203.08) and
  (317.04,204.51) .. (316.27,205.27) .. controls (315.44,206.10) and
  (313.84,205.42) .. (313.84,204.24) .. controls (313.84,203.47) and
  (314.59,202.66) .. (315.20,202.71) -- cycle(281.15,219.55) ..
  controls (282.26,219.50) and (283.28,221.59) .. (282.31,222.20) ..
  controls (280.99,223.04) and (279.96,222.62) .. (280.61,221.52) ..
  controls (280.88,221.05) and (280.92,220.81) .. (280.76,220.65) ..
  controls (280.40,220.29) and (280.49,219.73) .. (280.93,219.60) ..
  controls (281.00,219.57) and (281.08,219.55) .. (281.15,219.55) --
  cycle(266.57,228.02) .. controls (267.02,228.02) and
  (268.19,229.36) .. (268.11,229.78) .. controls (267.98,230.48) and
  (266.55,230.25) .. (266.13,229.46) .. controls (265.87,228.98) and
  (266.16,228.02) .. (266.57,228.02) -- cycle(261.57,235.37) ..
  controls (261.80,235.37) and (262.06,235.42) .. (262.32,235.52) ..
  controls (263.27,235.88) and (263.14,237.87) .. (262.14,238.25) ..
  controls (261.57,238.47) and (261.33,238.39) .. (260.77,237.81) ..
  controls (259.71,236.70) and (260.33,235.37) .. (261.57,235.37) --
  cycle(258.62,237.56) .. controls (259.87,237.56) and
  (260.62,239.58) .. (259.70,240.49) .. controls (259.28,240.91) and
  (257.72,240.92) .. (257.38,240.51) .. controls (256.62,239.59) and
  (257.47,237.56) .. (258.62,237.56) -- cycle(252.24,243.67) ..
  controls (252.42,243.67) and (252.65,243.69) .. (252.94,243.70) ..
  controls (254.82,243.79) and (255.07,244.68) .. (253.65,246.18) ..
  controls (252.14,247.78) and (250.64,246.39) .. (251.49,244.17) ..
  controls (251.63,243.79) and (251.71,243.68) .. (252.24,243.67) --
  cycle(250.22,252.18) .. controls (251.48,252.18) and
  (252.07,254.07) .. (251.07,254.91) .. controls (250.33,255.53) and
  (250.31,255.53) .. (249.66,255.09) .. controls (249.00,254.64) and
  (248.86,254.42) .. (248.86,253.80) .. controls (248.86,253.27) and
  (249.77,252.18) .. (250.22,252.18) -- cycle(233.00,272.72) ..
  controls (233.36,272.71) and (233.81,272.73) .. (234.37,272.73) ..
  controls (237.50,272.79) and (237.66,272.87) .. (237.72,274.63) ..
  controls (237.76,276.21) and (237.55,277.11) .. (236.94,277.93) ..
  controls (236.66,278.29) and (236.31,278.91) .. (236.14,279.30) ..
  controls (235.84,280.03) and (235.33,280.22) .. (234.88,279.77) ..
  controls (234.23,279.12) and (234.29,279.97) .. (234.95,280.81) ..
  controls (235.85,281.94) and (235.78,282.13) .. (234.39,282.20) ..
  controls (232.87,282.28) and (232.72,282.50) .. (232.70,284.66) ..
  controls (232.69,285.62) and (232.57,286.61) .. (232.44,286.85) ..
  controls (231.87,287.89) and (232.13,289.06) .. (233.11,290.00) ..
  controls (234.15,290.99) and (234.21,291.35) .. (233.71,293.31) ..
  controls (233.53,293.98) and (233.21,295.34) .. (232.99,296.33) ..
  controls (232.77,297.32) and (232.45,298.40) .. (232.29,298.71) ..
  controls (232.13,299.03) and (231.99,299.60) .. (231.99,299.98) ..
  controls (231.99,300.36) and (231.94,300.96) .. (231.87,301.31) ..
  controls (231.74,301.93) and (231.33,302.15) .. (231.07,301.73) ..
  controls (230.89,301.43) and (231.20,290.58) .. (231.40,290.04) ..
  controls (231.50,289.77) and (231.45,289.23) .. (231.28,288.67) ..
  controls (230.96,287.60) and (231.03,281.53) .. (231.40,278.10) ..
  controls (231.52,277.00) and (231.59,275.45) .. (231.56,274.65) ..
  controls (231.50,273.00) and (231.43,272.73) .. (233.00,272.72) --
  cycle(239.51,273.31) .. controls (241.25,273.31) and
  (242.16,275.09) .. (241.02,276.24) .. controls (240.84,276.41) and
  (240.59,276.54) .. (240.46,276.52) .. controls (240.33,276.51) and
  (239.90,276.45) .. (239.51,276.41) .. controls (237.76,276.21) and
  (237.76,273.31) .. (239.51,273.31) -- cycle(238.41,278.21) ..
  controls (238.47,278.21) and (238.53,278.22) .. (238.59,278.22) ..
  controls (239.43,278.31) and (239.52,278.99) .. (238.81,279.92) ..
  controls (237.77,281.28) and (236.87,281.23) .. (236.87,279.81) ..
  controls (236.87,278.89) and (237.54,278.22) .. (238.41,278.21) --
  cycle(234.40,283.25) .. controls (234.90,283.26) and
  (235.21,283.73) .. (234.72,284.38) .. controls (233.86,285.51) and
  (234.21,285.89) .. (235.29,284.98) .. controls (235.62,284.70) and
  (235.97,284.53) .. (236.07,284.59) .. controls (236.41,284.80) and
  (236.30,286.66) .. (235.94,286.79) .. controls (234.18,287.47) and
  (232.25,285.17) .. (233.41,283.78) .. controls (233.72,283.40) and
  (234.09,283.24) .. (234.40,283.25) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[shift={(6.569,0)}]
  \path[fill=black] (214.258,318.129) node[above right] (text3555) {0};
  \path[fill=black] (214.258,276.694) node[above right] (text3567) {1};
  \path[fill=black] (214.258,234.771) node[above right] (text3571) {2};
  \path[fill=black] (214.258,193.863) node[above right] (text3575) {3};
  \node[below left of=text3571] {$\frac{\overline{\mu}_z}{\mu_B}$};
\end{scope}
\path[fill=black] (275.327,328.022) node[above right] (text3559) {1};
\path[fill=black] (321.834,328.022) node[above right] (text3563) {2};
\path[fill=black] (368.305,328.022) node[above right] (text3579) {3};
\path[fill=black] (417.295,328.022) node[above right] (text3583) {4};
\path[fill=black] (228.608,328.022) node[above right] (text3559-4) {0};
  \node[below of=text3563] {$\frac{B}{T}$(T/K)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```